# Setup PHPStorm to debug symlinked WordPress plugin

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, wordpress

I'm using [Herbert](http://getherbert.com/dev/controllers) framework to develop a WordPress plugin. It recommends to set up a separate folder on a disk and symlink it to the "/wp-content/plugins/" directory.

I created a project in PHPStorm with a original plugin directory. Then I added "wp-includes" folder as external library to get all the Wordpress.

[image]

I also brought up a wordpress integration this way:
[image]

Now this is how I tried to configure the server to get this plugin debugged. That isn't working.
[image]

Can you guys please help me to debug it?

Comment: Just a note to your last image: you have provided a path for project files ... but have not done it to the include path entry .. why? It's either all or none at all ("use path mappings" is unchecked).